# Batch File that merges text files

Tags: batch-file, text-files, post-processing, g-code, cnc

I have a newbie question about batch files.

I have a CNC post that only lets me post one tool at a time.

I would like to have a batch file that merges all the text files in the post and puts them into one text file

the programmer can name the files 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004

then the batch file places 1002,1003,1004 into 1001

I would like it to delete the first 20 lines of 1002,1003,1004 as it will already be in the post 1001.

please let me know if this is doable or not

much appreciated!!!

-Aaron

Comment: do you have any piece of code to work with? things you've tried?

Comment: yes I do! ill add them to my post

Comment: actually do you think I could email them to you? I dont think I can post files on stack overflow

Comment: @AaronSteenland Look at some other questions and look at how people include code in their questions. You should copy and paste the relevant code into codeblocks using triple backticks.

Comment: i also need it to remove the m30% for the first three and keep it for the last text file

Comment: m30 basically loops the program back to the beginning

Comment: %
O01001
(Using high feed G1 F500. instead of G0.)
G90 G17
G20
(When using Fusion 360 for Personal Use, the feedrate of)
(rapid moves is reduced to match the feedrate of cutting)
(moves, which can increase machining time. Unrestricted rapid)
(moves are available with a Fusion 360 Subscription.)
G53 G0 Z0.

(Face1)
T1 M6
S6500 M3
G54
M8
G1 X2.925 Y-4.7456 F500.
G0 G43 Z0.6 H1
G1 Z0.2 F65.
G18 G3 X2.725 Z0. I-0.2 K0.
G18 G2 X2.8254 Z0.2 I0. K0.2
G1 Z0.6

M5
M9
G53 G0 Z0.
X0.
G53 G0 Y0.
M30

%

Comment: ^^ so I will have four text files containing g code like this. I need the first ten line of code deleted in all the text files after 1001

Comment: and I will need the last 4 lines deleted from the first three text files

Comment: then I would like them merged together

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  SO is not a free coding service so we need to see your attempt & make suggestions from there. We'd need a complete description of what you want to achieve from the get-go. The problem became far more complex when you belatedly added the `last 4 lines deleted` item, and you have conflicting requirements, stating `remove first 20 lines` in your narrative & `ten lines of code` in your comment. You can use the `edit` button to edit-in your code & we'd need a clear representative data sample (select the code/data & press `{}` to highlight) Is that `%` actually there?

Comment: "I have a CNC post that only lets me post one tool at a time." How do you know its your post processor? Those are just formatting instructions for you specific control.  I have never hear of a "post" that only allows 1 tool at a time and I have used everything from Mastercam2022 to old school geopath .  You need to reach out to your CAD/CAM retailer and get the correct post. You are tryin to solve a problem that should not exist to begin with.

Comment: If you have a common CNC machine like Haas, Mazak, DMG/Mori, Makino etc. there is a TON of support out there for you. If you have an uncommon brand then it may be more difficult, but even those guys generally copy the GE/FANUC control.  As someone who deals with this every day you should really just get the correct set up all the way from your machine and control definitions to the post you link them to.

Answer (score 0):

```
:: Read text 
set /p text1=<1001.txt
set /p text2=<1002.txt
set /p text3=<1003.txt
set /p text4=<1004.txt

:: Merge the text
echo %text1% >merged_text.txt
echo %text2% >>merged_text.txt
echo %text3% >>merged_text.txt
echo %text4% >>merged_text.txt

:: Display the merged text
type merged_text.txt
```

Comment: sorry, but that just collects the very first line of each file.

Comment: It is also helpful to add an explanation of the example code you have posted.